# trying to send link with querystrings as email

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
 Dim x As String
 x = "http://www.domain.com/aaa/test/default2.aspx?date=" & now.Text & "&tfname=" & p1fname.Text & "&tlname=" & p1lname.Text & "&comp=" & Request.QueryString("comp")

 Dim objEmail As New MailMessage()
 objEmail.To = "test@email.com"
 objEmail.From = "me@test.com"
 objEmail.Cc = "test@email.com"
 objEmail.Subject = "Test Email"
 objEmail.Body = x
 SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mail.domain.com"
 Try
     SmtpMail.Send(objEmail)
 Catch exc As Exception
     Response.Write("Send failure: " + exc.ToString())
 End Try
```

When I get the email it comes with

http://www.domain.com/aaa/test/default2.aspx?date=1/13/2011

as a link

and the rest as text

11:39:09 AM&tfname=sadasd&tlname=asd&comp=GWI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you put a parameter into a query string, you should encode it using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode to avoid invalid characters going into the URL:

```
x = "http://www.domain.com/aaa/test/default2.aspx?date=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(now.Text) &
    "&tfname=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p1fname.Text) &
    "&tlname=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(p1lname.Text) &
    "&comp=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString("comp"))
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have Spaces in the query string, if you need to put spaces, replace it with %20 before appending to the querystring. Although the ideal way to do this is to encrypt and decrpt the text in the querystring.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts the reason you see it as a link, is because gmail was smart enough to convert it for you. Because you have a space in it, google couldn't figure out where it ended. If you'd like to send it as a real link, use an anchor.

Comment: well for the date i am using datetime.now how can i format it to be a date and time with no spaces

Comment: @MyHeadHurts `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(DateTime.Now.ToString())`

Comment: @MyHeadHurts But just so you're aware, not every email tool will show that as a link. Most will just show it as text.

Comment: You can use the ToString override of the DateTime to provide a format for your date time, you can always just get the date part of the whole date and time with like a "-" inbetween rather than space.